# How to show iPhone app to the client without submitting to the app store (ad-hoc distribution)

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to show my app to the client without submitting to the app store. I was following the below instructions. But my app doesn't display in iTunes. Could you please help me?

1. Login to the iPhone developer portal website.
2. Add their iPhone UDID to the list of devices. Generate a provisioning profile that includes your own test phone and theirs. Download the file (ends with .mobileprovision).
3. Double-click it to install it on your development machine. Quit and restart Xcode, then set your code signing identity to the name of this profile. Build the binary.
4. In the left side of Xcode "Groups & Files" bar look for Products (may need to expand the folder).
5. Select {yourapp}.app. Right click and choose 'Reveal in Finder.' Now take that .app file and the .mobileprovision file you downloaded, zip them both up and send it to the client.
   They will need to unzip the archive, then drag-drop the .app and .mobileprovision onto their iTunes and sync the phone. Your app should show up and run.

The portal site has more detailed instructions, but this is basically it in a nutshell.

Answer (score 3):

[TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) is a great free service to do most of the hard work here for you. Follow [these instructions](http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4) for generating an IPA file and distribute it to whomever you like, without having to go through iTunes.

You still have to follow steps 1, 2 and 3 from your existing instructions.

Answer (score 0):

First create distribution profile using apple developer portal you can follow this tutorial.

http://www.manyfriends.com/wiki/iphone/index.php/Create_an_ad-hoc_provisioning_profile

After installing profile follow this to create a binary that you will send to you client.

http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/